# How to truncate the number of digits after the decimal

Tags: java

Suppose, I take an irrational number, q, and an integer n, and I want to print the truncated value of q after keeping exactly n digits after the decimal.

Example: 
Input: q = 3.14159625, n = 3
Output: 3.141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `System.out.printf` assuming you want correct rounding

```
String format = "%." + n + "f";
System.out.printf(format, q);

int n = 3;
float q = 3.141592625f;

String format = "%." + n + "f";
System.out.printf(format, q);
```

**output**

```
3.142
```

if you really want to truncate you can convert to a String, then

```
int n = 3;
float q = 3.141592625f;
String str = Float.toString(q);
int index = str.indexOf('.');
System.out.println(str.substring(0, index + n + 1));
```

**output**

```
3.141
```

but you will need to check for valid index of and string length

Comment: I want that output will be 3.141, not 3.142

Comment: so look at the second block of code I gave you, also as per the duplicate link you could use `BigDecimal`

Comment: yeah that's my answer, thank you. Currently, I can't able to upvote because of less reputation, as soon as I get required reputation I'll upvote your answer.